# AWS Cognito adminSetUserPassword returns "User does not exist." when user is definitely in pool

Tags: php, amazon-cognito, aws-php-sdk

When calling the following code it returns an exception

```php
$this->client->adminSetUserPassword([
                'Password'          => $password,
                'Permanent'         => true,
                'UserPoolId'        => $this->poolId,
                'Username'          => $email,
            ]);

-errorCode: "UserNotFoundException"
-errorMessage: "User does not exist."
```

I'm using similar admin level requests elsewhere as follows...

```php
$result = $this->client->adminDeleteUser([
                    'UserPoolId' => $this->poolId,
                    'Username'   => $email,
                ]);

$result = $this->client->adminDisableUser([
                'UserPoolId' => $this->poolId,
                'Username'   => $email,
            ]);

$response = $this->client->adminInitiateAuth([
                'AuthFlow'       => 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
                'AuthParameters' => [
                    'USERNAME'     => $email,
                    'PASSWORD'     => $password,
                    'SECRET_HASH'  => $this->cognitoSecretHash($email),
                ],
                'ClientId'   => $this->clientId,
                'UserPoolId' => $this->poolId,
            ]);
```

All these methods and others work correctly with the user, but the new adminSetUserPassword method seems to fail, despite the user definitely being in my user pool.

Comment: Did you test this API call via the AWS CLI too?

Comment: Have you tried using your Cognito specific ID?

E.g. XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX